# Spyder appends Tensorboard summary files

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, spyder, tensorboard

When I run my python code from a console, everything works fine: I get one new tensorboard file (626 bytes) every time and I can look it up using the Tensorboard service.

But, when I run this code from Spyder IDE, after every run there is a new file that contains data from **all** the runs made in Spyder since it's started. After 10 runs executed in Spyder, even when I shut down tensorboard server and delete dir with logs, after 11th run there will be a new file with approximately 6K size, containg all of the previous runs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(2,name ='a')
b = tf.constant(3,name = 'b')
x = tf.add(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
# add this line to use TensorBoard.
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs', sess.graph)

    print (sess.run(x))

    writer.close() # close the writer when you’re done using i
```

After Spyder restart whole story starts again, first run produces correct result, while second already contains its predecessor data.

Spyder IDE does some caching or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found an answer to my own question. There is a setting in Spyder: Tools -> Preferences -> Run -> 'Clear all variables before execution'

(also in Run -> Configuration per file... -> 'Clear all variables before execution')

Details: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2563